# Scale a big div inside a little div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `.little` block, which is always has 300px width.
And i have `.big` block, which may have 500px, 800px, 1000px, etc.
I need a solution, how to show big div inside a little.
Without `overflow:scroll;` or `overflow:hidden;`. I need a solution by scaling.

Like when you open desktop website version on a phone and it shows all website without horizontal scrolling or like big image can be covered inside an little block.

```
<div class="little">
  <div class="big">
    Text, images and other content 
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.little{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.big{
  width: 800px; /*can be different*/
  height: 1000px;  /*can be different*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to set specific CSS if your big div is inside your little div using `max-width` and `max-height` ?

```css
.little{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.big{
  width: 800px; /*can be different*/
  height: 1000px;  /*can be different*/
}
.little .big {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This will (I think) cut rest of big div´s content. I think he wanted to scale bigger element

Comment: @throrin19 I need a scale

Comment: It depends of the content. If it's text, yes it will be crop (and it's normal). For images, if you have correct CSS in it, it will be scale correctly.

@Daishiro In that case, it depends of your div content. This is the basic CSS usage to resize big div in small div but without informations of the big div content and what you want exaclty, the response must be different.